# Can't find screenshotted photos in Minecraft Technic Launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I screenshotted some photos in Minecraft
and I can't find them. I play Minecraft on a Technic Launcher and I have a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots taken in Minecraft on MacOS (using the in-game function, by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), are stored in the directory `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/screenshots`.

The [source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Screenshot) additionally provides the following as an alternative for finding your screenshots:

> You can also access the screenshots folder by going to "Resource
> Packs" in the settings menu, clicking on "Open resource pack folder",
> and going up one level.

In your case, using the Technic Launcher, they might also be stored in the folder of the mod you were using when you took the screenshots, meaning in `~/Library/Application Support/techniclauncher/modfolder` (see [here](https://forums.technicpack.net/topic/145818-screenshots/)).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get to the screens really easily:

`%appdata%/.technic/modpacks/[your pack]/screenshots`